# What is the scope of the variables passed to subtemplates in QWeb?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-13, qweb

I am using Odoo 13, but this is a QWeb question:

I got the following template in QWeb:

```
<template id="my_subtemplate">
    <t t-set="foo" t-value="foo + 1"/>
    <p>Inside subtemplate: <t t-esc="foo"/></p>
</template>
```

In other template, I call it twice, this way:

```
<t t-set="foo" t-value="1"/>
<t t-call="my_module.my_subtemplate"/>
<t t-call="my_module.my_subtemplate"/>
<p>Inside main template: <t t-esc="foo"/></p>
```

So when I call the main template, I expect to get this result:

```
Inside subtemplate: 2
Inside subtemplate: 3
Inside main template: 3
```

However, I am getting this one:

```
Inside subtemplate: 2
Inside subtemplate: 2
Inside main template: 1
```

Can't variables be modified in a subtemplate? Any ideas of how to do such a simple task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the first question: seems it's not possible in subtemplates. A quote from the 13.0 doc:

> Alternatively, content set in the body of the call directive will be
> evaluated before calling the sub-template, and **can alter a local
> context**:

I interpret "local context" as the scope of your inner `foo` stays in the subtemplate, like having a copy of the outer `foo`.

Second question: difficult. You could use loops, like:

```xml
<t t-set="foo" t-value="1"/>
<t t-for="your_iterable" t-as="item">
  <t t-set="foo" t-value="foo + 1"/>
  <t t-call="my_module.my_subtemplate"/>
<p>Inside main template: <t t-esc="foo"/></p>

<!-- subtemplate without t-set!!! -->
```

Could work, because now `foo` stays in the same scope all the time.

Comment: Good alternative solution, I've tried and it works, and I've changed my mind, I'm going to use it. My question shows a simple example but actually I had a loop inside the subtemplate. I've extracted it out of the subtemplate as you wrote me. Now the code is less simple but at least it works!